# Pandas - Conditional Calculation Based on Shift Values from Two Other Columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure this question is easy, but it has been stumping me for too long, so would REALLY appreciate some direction

I'm looking to add a column to a dataframe based on the results of two other columns

I want to identify if the stock is equal to the stock in the prior row and the date is equal to the date in the prior row.

I am looking to get the running count 
I tried something along the lines of the following

```
df['DayCount']=np.where(df['ticker'] ==df['ticker'].shift()) & np.where(df['trade_date']==df['trade_date'].shift() ,  1, 0)
```

and

```
df['DayCount'] = df.where(df['ticker'] ==df['ticker'].shift() &    df['trade_date']==df['trade_date'].shift(),1,0)
```

Sample input

```
Stock, Date, Time, Price 
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:01, 50.5
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:02, 50.7
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:03, 50.9
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:02, 52.7
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:03, 52.9
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:02, 520.31
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:03, 520.92
```

And output:

```
Stock, Date,Time, Price, DayCount 
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:01, 50.5,1
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:02, 50.7,2
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:03, 50.9,3
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:02, 52.7,1
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:03, 52.9,2
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:02, 520.31,1
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:03, 520.92,2
```

I got errors like

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'
```

And then applying a `cumulative count`.

First, and this is most important to me, how do you write the initial statement so that you can do the compare over multiple columns

Second, how would you add in the `cumulative count`?

Thank you so much for helping

Expanding on the original post, here is another question.. Assume now that the data set is slightly different

```
Stock, Date, Time, Price,BidOffer
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:01, 50.5, bid
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:02, 50.7, offer
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:03, 50.9, bid
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:02, 52.7, bid
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:03, 52.9, bid
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:02, 520.31, offer
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:03, 520.92, offer
```

And we are looking to see how many times in a row stocks traded on the bid or offer, so the output would be:

```
Stock, Date, Time, Price,BidOffer,Count
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:01, 50.5, bid, 1 
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:02, 50.7, offer, 1
IBM, 2014-09-01, 12:30:03, 50.9, bid,1
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:02, 52.7, bid,1
IBM, 2014-09-02, 09:57:03, 52.9, bid,2
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:02, 520.31, offer,1
AAPL, 2014-11-02, 09:57:03, 520.92, offer,2
```

Groupings are effectively Stock and Date, time is just used to determine sequence.. any help much appreciated on this expansion

Comment: are you here just trying to get the duplicate row based on stock and date?

Comment: No...  Its more of a datetime thing, I want to find the first trade of the day, second print of the day, etc...  Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE3:** *"And we are looking to see how many times in a row stocks traded on the bid or offer"*

```
In [112]: g = df.groupby(['Stock','Date'])

In [113]: df['Count'] = g['BidOffer'].apply(lambda x: (x == x.shift()).cumsum()) + 1

In [114]: df
Out[114]:
  Stock       Date      Time   Price BidOffer  Count
0   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:01   50.50      bid      1
1   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:02   50.70    offer      1
2   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:03   50.90      bid      1
3   IBM 2014-09-02  09:57:02   52.70      bid      1
4   IBM 2014-09-02  09:57:03   52.90      bid      2
5  AAPL 2014-11-02  09:57:02  520.31    offer      1
6  AAPL 2014-11-02  09:57:03  520.92    offer      2
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [515]: df['DayCount'] = df.groupby(['Stock', 'Date', 'BidOffer']).cumcount() + 1

In [516]: df
Out[516]:
  Stock       Date      Time   Price BidOffer  DayCount
0   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:01   50.50      bid         1
1   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:02   50.70    offer         1
2   IBM 2014-09-01  12:30:03   50.90      bid         2
3   IBM 2014-09-02  09:57:02   52.70      bid         1
4   IBM 2014-09-02  09:57:03   52.90      bid         2
5  AAPL 2014-11-02  09:57:02  520.31    offer         1
6  AAPL 2014-11-02  09:57:03  520.92    offer         2
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [489]: df['DayCount'] = df.groupby(['Stock', df.Datetime.dt.date]).cumcount() + 1

In [490]: df
Out[490]:
  Stock            Datetime   Price  DayCount
0   IBM 2014-09-01 12:30:01   50.50         1
1   IBM 2014-09-01 12:30:02   50.70         2
2   IBM 2014-09-01 12:30:03   50.90         3
3   IBM 2014-09-02 09:57:02   52.70         1
4   IBM 2014-09-02 09:57:03   52.90         2
5  AAPL 2014-11-02 09:57:02  520.31         1
6  AAPL 2014-11-02 09:57:03  520.92         2
```

**Answer for the original question:**

```
df['DayCount']=np.where(
                  (df['ticker']==df['ticker'].shift())
                  &
                  (df['trade_date']==df['trade_date'].shift()),
                  1,
                  0
)
```

The only thing that was missing in your second solution is parenthesis: `np.where( (...) & (...), 1, 0)`

Comment: I feel so stupid - thanks!  How do I apply the rolling count in there?

Comment: @Jeff, there is absolutely nothing stupid in your question! About rolling count - could you post a sample input data set and desired output DF, because it's not quite clear?

Comment: @Jeff, please see "UPDATE"

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114426/discussion-between-jeff-and-maxu).

Comment: @Jeff, please check UPDATE3

Comment: That is truly awesome.. Thank you.. Wish I could give this answer 100 thumbs up.  Saved me a ton of time